# RACSignal and an array of view models, is there a more reactive way?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

I use `UITableViewController` to show discovered devices. They are obtained from `SDDeviceBrowser`, which scans for them constantly and calls its delegate method each time a new device is found. I created a `RACSignal` like this:

```
@implementation SDDeviceBrowser (RAC)
- (RACSignal*)rac_newDeviceSignal {
    return [self rac_signalForSelector:@selector(deviceBrowserDidFindNewDevice:) fromProtocol:@protocol(SDDeviceBrowserDelegate)];
}
@end
```

I use MVVM pattern: my table view's view model is `DeviceListViewModel`. It has an array `devices`, containing child view models which are bound to table view cells. It maps the browser's signal and exposes it for the view controller:

```
@interface DeviceListViewModel ()
@property (strong, readwrite, nonatomic) NSArray *devices;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SDDeviceBrowser *browser;
@end

//boring initialization ommitted

- (RACSignal *)deviceFoundSignal {
    return [[self.browser rac_newDeviceSignal] map:^id(RACTuple* parameters) {
      SDDevice *device = parameters.last;
      DeviceViewModel *deviceViewModel = [[DeviceViewModel alloc] initWithDevice:device];
      self.devices = [self.devices arrayByAddingObject:deviceViewModel];
      return deviceViewModel;
    }];
}
```

Then the table view controller subscribes to `deviceFoundSignal` and inserts a row whenever a new device is found:

```
[[self.viewModel.deviceFoundSignal throttle:0.5] subscribeNext:^(id value) {
  [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
  //insert new rows to the table view inside beginUpdates/endUpdates 
}];
```

It is also possible to "reset" the device browser: it clears the list of discovered devices and starts scanning again. However, I couldn't find a nice reactive solution to handle that - I just do the following (in the view controller):

```
[[self.refreshControl rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
  [self.viewModel restartScanning];  //clears the 'devices' array and restarts the browser
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

This works, but I think it could be done in a more "reactive" way. Adding new view model to the array inside the `map:` block looks kinda ugly. Am I missing any  features of ReactiveCocoa that can be used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For assembling the array of devices, check out [`-scanWithStart:reduce:`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/fcd26bd9a7c08dcdb16613f6dcee8a728391f927/ReactiveCocoa/RACStream.h#L227-255). With this method, you could start with an empty array, and have the reduce block add each device to the array. For example:

```
[[[self.browser
    rac_newDeviceSignal]
    map:^(RACTuple *parameters) {
        SDDevice *device = parameters.last;
        return [[DeviceViewModel alloc] initWithDevice:device];
    }]
    scanWithStart:@[] reduce:^(NSArray models, DeviceViewModel *deviceViewModel) {
        return [devices arrayByAddingObject:deviceViewModel];
    }]
```

This doesn't do much for the "reset" functionality. To combine "adding" and "reseting" into one signal and one scan, I would do the following:

First, find somewhere in your code that you can expose the two pertinent signals, namely `-rac_newDeviceSignal` and which ever signal represents the events that causes a reset. I'll call this latter signal "`resetSignal`".

With a signal of device additions, and a signal of resets, I would map them each to "operations" on the array of devices. What do I mean by "operation", basically a block that takes the old array of devices, and returns a new array of devices.

```
RACSignal *addOperation = [[self.browser rac_newDeviceSignal] map:^(RACTuple *parameters) {
    return ^(NSArray *devices) {
        SDDevice *device = parameters.last;
        DeviceViewModel *model = [[DeviceViewModel alloc] initWithDevice:device];
        return [devices arrayByAddingObject:model];
    };
}]

RACSignal *resetOperation = [resetSignal map:^(id _) {
    return ^(NSArray *devices) {
        return @[];
    };
}]
```

With these two signals in place, they can be `+merge:`'d into a single signal, which can then be scanned on like shown up above.

```
[[RACSignal
    merge:@[ addOperation, resetOperation ]]
    scanWithStart:@[] reduce:(NSArray *devices, NSArray *(^operation)(NSArray *)) {
        return operation(devices);
    }]
```